# Rails helper method error content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am ruby beginner, I am following a rails course, and this method works for the instructor but not for me, I get a syntax error.

```
module SubjectsHelper
    def status_tag (boolean, options={})
        options[:true_text] ||= ''
        options[:false_text] ||= ''

        if boolean
            content_tag (:span, options[:true_text], :class => "status true")
        else
            content_tag (:span, options[:false_text], :class => "status false")
        end

    end
end
```

The error I get is:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' content_tag (:span, options[:true_text], :class => "status true") ^

The line number in error message points to the first call to `content_tag`. I have double checked with the video, and I don't know what is wrong,

I event tried wrapping `:class => "status true"` in `{}` and I got the same error.

Comment: Try remove the space between `content_tag` and `(` or you can suppress `(` and `)`

Comment: so ruby is not white space insensitive?

Comment: Exactly, Ruby is not white space insensitive, as you can see here: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2008/7/1/whitespace-sensitivity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this to

```
content_tag(:span, options[:true_text], class: "status true")
```

please read the docs before using a method. Here is docs for [content_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)